# DockerでpostgresqlDBの永続化について

Tags: postgresql, docker

### 概要

Dockerで作成したPostgreSQLサーバのディレクトリをホストにマウントできず困っています。

---

### 質問内容

DockerでPostgreSQLを用いたデータベースコンテナを作成しようとしています。
postgres公式のイメージを使用し、データを永続化させるため、
/var/lib/postgresql/dataをホストのvolディレクトリにマウントして実行しようとし、
以下のコマンドを実行しましたが、コンテナが起動しません。

**実行したコマンド**

```
$ docker run -d -p 5432:5432 -v `pwd`/vol:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:9.6.2
```

※-vオプションを指定しなければ、起動することができました。

他のサイトではこの方法でマウントできると書いてありましたが、コンテナが起動しない原因つていて、なにか考えられることはないでしょうか。

環境は以下の通りです。

- Windows 10（64bit）
- Docker Quickstart Terminal
- VirtualBox 5.1.0

あまり詳しくないので、常識的な質問でしたら申し訳ありません。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 起動しない場合に表示されるエラーメッセージがあれば、それを追記していただけますか。

Comment: エラーメッセージは表示されません。
コンテナは作成されるようですが、起動ができません。

Comment: ログは[`docker logs [コンテナID]`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/)コマンドで見ることができます。ちなみに私の環境では該当コマンドで問題なくコンテナが起動しています。

Answer (score -1):

VirtualBoxではdockerを使っていないのですが、`` `pwd` `` が余計では？
`` `pwd`/vol `` の部分を絶対パスにしてみてはいかがでしょうか。